How to calculate a generalized integral
I have problem with the following integral:
$$ 
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{{\rm e}^{{\rm i}k\left(r + xa\right)}}{r}{\rm d}r\quad
\mbox{where}\quad k,\ b\ \mbox{and}\ a\ \mbox{are constants}
$$
$$
\mbox{such that}\quad
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
b,\ k > 0
\\[1mm]
-1 \leq a \leq 1
\\[1mm]
r = \,\sqrt{\,{x^{2} + b^{2}}\,}\,
\end{array}\right.
$$

I guess that it need to use Residue Theorem from the Complex Analysis, but I have no idea to calculate it precisely.
What is the result of this integral ?.

Could you please give me some help with details ?. Thanks in advance.

Your integral is a sort of Fourier integral, where you write instead of $r=\sqrt{x^2+b^2}$.
Try to do as suggested in the follwing ppt:
https://courses.egr.uh.edu/ECE/ECE6382/Class%20Notes/Notes%2011%206382%20Integral%20Evaluation.pdf
on pages 13-15.
Obviously you need to separate between two options: $a><0$.

I don't think it answers the question. The PDF you shared does not talk about what to do with denominators of the type ${\sqrt{x^2 + b^2}}$

Yes, it seems you are correct, @ArchismanPanigrahi I had seen this sort of integral quite a lot in a course in Condensed Matter Physics 1. I mean when looking at an integral of the sort of $\sin(kr)/r$... Usually you would multiply by an exponent of $e^{-\alpha x}$ and then the solution will let $\alpha \to 0$. I think it's called regularization or something like that.

It does not seem to be a common integral encountered in CMP. $\sin(kr)/r$ can be integrated $-\infty$ to $\infty$, but this is a different integral.

This is not a Answer. Using only Mathematica:
$$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{\exp \left(i k \left(\sqrt{x^2+b^2}+x a\right)\right)}{\sqrt{x^2+b^2}} \, dx=2 K_0\left(-\sqrt{k^2 \left(-1+| a| ^2\right)} | b| \right)$$
where:$K_0$ is  the modified Bessel function of the second kind.

Can you add more details about how to obtain that?
